# How to write equations in the SELECT area

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, trim

I have 2 tables that I've Joined, One contains "Materials" and the other contains "Moldings". They are joined by the Material ID.

I want the end result to be a table of all of the unique materials being used.

The issue I'm running into is that the materials have lengths in the name. (eg. 10' Maple, 8' Maple) and I would like to exclude them when getting unique materials.

What I get now:

```
10' Maple
8' Maple
3' Maple
7' Cherry
```

What I want:

```
Maple
Cherry
```

What I have now is my attempt at getting rid of the numbers as it selects the table. Though my limited SQL knowledge is making it difficult.

```
SELECT LTrim(Right([CxMaterial].[Name],Len([CxMaterial].[Name])-5)) AS [EditedMaterial]
FROM [Molding] INNER JOIN
     [CxMaterial]
     ON [Molding].[Material ID] = [CxMaterial].[ID] 
GROUP BY [EditedMaterial]
```

The RIGHT and LEN are to get rid of the numbers
The Trim is to trim the spaces (as some have 2 digits and some have 1)

The main errors are "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'LTRIM(...-5))' as part of an aggregate function"

and a bunch of syntax errors when I attempt to fix that problem

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SQL Server.

If you just want everything after the first space, you can use `stuff()` and `charindex()`:

```
select stuff(str, 1, charindex(' ', str), '')
from (values ('7'' Cherry')) v(str)
```

Comment: gives me:
Undefined function 'STUFF' in expression

I'm making reports in Cabinet Vision, and they generate those based off of a database. I'm also assuming SQL Server, but I'm not sure if they play by their own rules or not.

Comment: @Matt . . . `STUFF()` is part of SQL Server, which is what your query looks like.  However, you should be tagging your question with the database, as I've already asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `SUBSTRING()` and `CHARINDEX()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([CxMaterial].[Name], CHARINDEX(' ',[CxMaterial].[Name]),[CxMaterial].[Name])) AS [EditedMaterial]
FROM [Molding] INNER JOIN
     [CxMaterial]
     ON [Molding].[Material ID] = [CxMaterial].[ID] 
GROUP BY [EditedMaterial]
```

Comment: I did try that first, however, it didn't seem to like those functions.
I'm using a program called Cabinet Vision. In it there are reports generated based on a database, so i'm not sure it follows all the same rules. 

I copy/pasted what you gave me and it's saying there is an Unknown Error :[ADODC]: Unknown error. [ADO]:

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it

```
SELECT (LTrim(Right([CxMaterial].[Name],Len([CxMaterial].[Name])-5)))

FROM ([Molding] INNER JOIN [CxMaterial] ON [Molding].[Material ID] = [CxMaterial].[ID])  

GROUP BY (LTrim(Right([CxMaterial].[Name],Len([CxMaterial].[Name])-5)))
```

It works, though I find it odd that it didn't before